# bundler error and having issues to reinstall after delete RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I deleted RVM, because I already had RBENV install. Now I cannot get bundler to work. This caused major issues. When I installed bundler again to run bundle i on my code, it gives me an error and it's looking for RVM.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/rvm
```

Comment: When you run `bundle` your computer is still looking into  rvm apparently. Run a `which bundle`, also make sure you delete all RVM left overs from your path, and make sure your RBENV path is setup correctly.

Ultimately all `which ruby`, `which gem`, `which bundle` should point to somewhere inside RBENV.

Comment: that fix it. Thank you!